# I am making masked face detection application with OpenCV that detect faces that wear masks but I got an error

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import cv2
import os


def detect_and_predict_mask(frame, faceNet, maskNet):
    (h, w) = frame.shape[:2]
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1.0, (300, 300),
                                 (104.0, 177.0, 123.0))
    faceNet.setInput(blob)
    detections = faceNet.forward()
    faces = []
    locs = []
    preds = []

    for i in range(0, detections.shape[2]):
        confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]
        if confidence > args["confidence"]:
            box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
            (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")
            (startX, startY) = (max(0, startX), max(0, startY))
            (endX, endY) = (min(w - 1, endX), min(h - 1, endY))
            face = frame[startY:endY, startX:endX]
            face = cv2.cvtColor(face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            face = cv2.resize(face, (224, 224))
            face = img_to_array(face)
            face = preprocess_input(face)
            face = np.expand_dims(face, axis=0)
            faces.append(face)
            locs.append((startX, startY, endX, endY))

    if len(faces) > 0:
        preds = maskNet.predict(faces)
    return (locs, preds)


ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-f", "--face", type=str,
                default="face_detector",
                help="path to face detector model directory")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", type=str,
                default="mask_detector.model",
                help="path to trained face mask detector model")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.5,
                help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
print("[INFO] loading face detector model...")
prototxtPath = os.path.sep.join([args["face"], "deploy.prototxt"])
weightsPath = os.path.sep.join([args["face"],
                                "res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel"])
faceNet = cv2.dnn.readNet(prototxtPath, weightsPath)

print("[INFO] loading face mask detector model...")
maskNet = load_model(args["model"])

print("[INFO] starting video stream...")
vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
time.sleep(2.0)

while True:
    frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=400)
    (locs, preds) = detect_and_predict_mask(frame, faceNet, maskNet)
    for (box, pred) in zip(locs, preds):
        (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box
        (mask, withoutMask) = pred
        label = "Mask" if mask > withoutMask else "No Mask"
        color = (0, 255, 0) if label == "Mask" else (0, 0, 255)
        label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(label, max(mask, withoutMask) * 100)
        cv2.putText(frame, label, (startX, startY - 10),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, color, 2)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), color, 2)

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()
```

Is there any modules that I need to import

Or is it all imported correctly.

I do not debug it

I reformat file one time.

I have got all of the needed xml and jpg files.

I have import all of the modules that is needed... I think so

*Below is the error*

Can you help me pls Im new to OpenCV and got an complicated error like this

**Thanks to all of Stackoverflow community for help:)**

```
C:\Users\Toshiba\Desktop\python_temelleri\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Toshiba/Desktop/python_temelleri/detect_mask_video.py
2020-08-28 16:47:05.729423: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-08-28 16:47:05.730054: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Toshiba/Desktop/python_temelleri/detect_mask_video.py", line 60, in <module>
    faceNet = cv2.dnn.readNet(prototxtPath, weightsPath)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-2b5g8ysb\opencv\modules\dnn\src\caffe\caffe_io.cpp:1121: error: (-2:Unspecified error) FAILED: fs.is_open(). Can't open "face_detector\deploy.prototxt" in function 'cv::dnn::ReadProtoFromTextFile'

[INFO] loading face detector model...

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Comment: No.
I don't understand anything even if I read

Comment: Try to Google "Can't open "face_detector\deploy.prototxt" in function 'cv::dnn::ReadProtoFromTextFile'"

Comment: Okay.Thanks:):):):):):):):):):):):):))::):)):))::)):):):):):):):):):):):):):):)):):):):):)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either don't provide models or the paths to the model are not correct. print the values of prototxtPath and weightsPath to check if you provide correct paths to the models.

Comment: Thanks for your answer:)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))

Comment: I cannot give an upvote I think.StackOverflow says 'Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.'.